# encrypt login credentials with jquery and decrypt with c++

Tags: jquery, c++, password-encryption

Could anyone please suggest me way of encrypting login credentials with jquery at client side and decrypting with c++ at server side other than hashing mechanism.

Thanks:)

Comment: Hashing isn't encryption/decryption. Do you need symmetric encryption or asymmetric encryption?

Comment: Please suggest me asymmetric encryption

Comment: An example of asymmetric encryption would be RSA and an example of a library that can do RSA encryption is OpenSSL.

Comment: Initially I created keys using openssl and sent public key to client. CryptJs jquery is used to encrypt the credentials with public key and passed that encrypted text to server just as post data and write it to a file server side. when I use that file to decrypt using openssl it's throwing few errors. Please explain or provide links to implement

Comment: Please some1 help me on this.....